# Funding as a newly graduated PhD

Tags: funding, postdocs

So at last I have graduated. I experienced my ex advisor 'dropping me' more or less, and focusing on his own tasks. He no longer communicates with me about anything relevant, and it seems my employment with the university as a research position will come to an end unless I seek funding alone.

Applying for industrial postdocs to get funding this way seems a little counter-intuitive considering I could spend all that time looking for an industry job. Alternatively, I've looked at grants but most things seem to be PhD age 2+. I spoke with a career counselor who confirmed this.

How does one continue working in the same environment if there's no support from their side regarding funding and I'm meant to find it alone? Is this a clear sign I should move on?

Comment: This probably depends on the country you are in. Also, your field.

Comment: I'd rather not disclose that, but the career counselor is research support and is well versed in the options in this country.

Comment: Very difficult to give an answer then. A tenure track STEM person in the US would be totally different from, well, lots of other things.

Comment: It's somewhere in Europe. And I don't have a tenure track position.

Comment: In my field (mathematics), the usual step for people finishing their Ph.D.'s is to apply for postdoctoral positions at other universities.

Comment: My field is computer science. My boss tells me he'd like to keep me but I have to apply for my own funding.

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to do a postdoc, with your PhD advisor who no longer wants to actually work with you, and asks you to get your own funding?

Comment: My ex advisor has stated he'd like to continue working with me, but his conduct suggests otherwise. So I'm stuck in a limbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, congratulations on finishing! It's a big achievement.

If I were you I would be applying for post-doc positions and/or industry positions ASAP. It depends on whether you want to stay in academia or work in industry.

Think about what you want to do and don't get misled by your ex-advisors mixed messages - if he really wanted to continue working with you, he would help you find funding instead of leaving it all up to you. If you really are interested in staying with him then ask him if he could give you advice on what funding you can apply for as newly graduated PhD.

Comment: "if he really wanted to continue working with you, he would help you find funding instead of leaving it all up to you" - Yeah, that's what I needed to hear. :) Thanks.